# How to create pages automatically with php? (More details inside)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a news website with php-mysql.

---

This is the table:

```
news_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
news_title VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
news_short_description TEXT NOT NULL,
news_full_content TEXT NOT NULL,
news_author VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
news_published_on DATE NOT NULL
)";
```

---

on the index page of the website will be shown the articles.

---

```
$sql = "SELECT news_id,news_title,news_short_description,news_full_content,news_author,news_published_on FROM ARTICOLI ORDER BY news_id DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<h3>". $row["news_title"]. " </h3><br> " . $row["news_short_description"]. "<br> " ."Posted by ". $row["news_author"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

---

WHAT I NEED?
i don't know how to create automatic pages and links for the single articles.
EXAMPLE: www.website.com/this-is-the-title-of-the-article.
i was thinking about using the id of the db table,but how to select one precise row? 
can you help me? thanks!!! ;)

Comment: You can use `where clause` to select specific row.

Comment: "but how to select one precise row?" - `WHERE news_id = 1` will select only the row where `news_id` is `1`.

Comment: So what's your criteria for precise row?

Comment: `WHERE news_id = '.(int)$_GET['news_id'].'`

Comment: thanks! and do you have any ideas for the url? :)

Comment: @DiegoTedesco keep it in the scope of your original question, please. Your question was how to select a single row from database, you have been given a few answers already

Answer (score 1):

One idea.
First of all, you need to add a slug field in your table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) which will hold the title in the form of `this-is-the-title-of-the-article`.

The assumption here would be that the "slug" will need to be a unique string in the table.

Secondly, you need to use some sort of rewrite mechanism (e.g. apache's mod_rewrite) to convert request of the form  www.website.com/this-is-the-title-of-the-article to something you can handle via a PHP script.
For example www.website.com/this-is-the-title-of-the-article gets rewritten as as www.website.com/index.php?q=this-is-the-title-of-the-article).

**Example .htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
 $articleSlug = isset($_GET(["q"])?$_GET["q"]:null;

 if ($articleSlug !== null) {
     $query = "SELECT news_id,news_title,news_short_description,news_full_content,news_author,news_published_on FROM ARTICOLI WHERE slug=?"; // Bind the ? to $articleSlug
      //Execute SQL here and echo the results
} else {
   // 404 error
}
```

I understand this is a very vague description and this is only one way of doing it. I would personally suggest you look into an MVC framework like e.g. Laravel which has all of this functionality already built in.